# Where can I rent a computer monitor for two weeks in Hong Kong?

Tags: electronic-items, hong-kong, rental

Where can I rent a computer monitor for two weeks in Hong Kong?

I'm looking for average sized computer monitors, i.e. around 24 to 27 inches. I found http://www.argo-tech.hk/ but the prices I was quoted ([2400.00 HKD](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&biw=1745&bih=775&ei=R-2_W6PMBOvB0PEPsLiygAU&q=2400.00+HKD+to+USD&oq=2400.00+HKD+to+USD&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0i22i30.1545.1799..2025...0.0..0.78.156.2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.vjpfmkYHMEo) for two 27-inch monitors) is higher than buying monitors, which defeats the purpose of renting.

Comment: Would buying a used monitor and selling it again on departure be an option?

Comment: @jpatokal let's say it's option B (as reselling slightly before leaving is a bit annoying), but I'm definitely interested to know what platforms Hong Kong folks use for buy/sell used  computer monitors.

Comment: For your question in the comment, there are quite a number of electronic/computer shops in Mong Kok, Wan Chai, and Sham Shui Po that buy/sell electronics including computer monitors. Two caveats: 1) They usually don't do websites - walk ins (and cash) only, 2) Nowadays lots of them focus on phones as they are more profitable, and you need to be more paitient.

Comment: To get rid of old monitors, people usually leave it with te Government's WEEE recycling program (without financial reward), leave it with "the recycling guy" lurking on the street (getting perhaps 10-20 HKD back), or donate it to a charity for those from a disadvantaged background. This is actually a great question worth for me to do some local research on - hold tight.

Comment: Do you not have any contacts in HK? Surely any office-based business has a couple of these spare and most people who work for such a business might be able to borrow one. Also I'm wondering - if you're in a hotel or Airbnb or similar, why not just use the TV?

Comment: @topomorto it's difficult for an employee to take company equipment back home. TVs have typically low resolution and/or are too large (>32-inch diagonal), and I need more than 1 computer monitor.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt it is a pain, but I just thought it is probably less difficult than buying monitors and selling them again in such a short timeframe. Some TVs are low-res, some are 4K - though I know a 'TV' often isn't really a good monitor.

Answer (score 3):

To be honest, it simply wouldn’t be worth the time and effort to rent what is now a commodity.

You could probably pick up a couple of low end monitors for $1,000 each in Sham Shui Po.  You can buy cheaper on one of the many Facebook buy and sell groups.

If you also post them for sale as soon as you buy them you have a fairly good chance of getting 40-50% back once you are done with them.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's plan B. If it was for just one computer monitor, that'd be ok, but I have a multimonitor set-up and travel for than once a year, so it adds up over time. When I was in India some company rented a few monitors to me at a decently cheap price, and they came to my place to deliver and pick up the monitors, so it was quite handy. (aside from the part where I had to speak Telugu for delivery instructions)

Comment: That’s my point.  With Hong Kong labour costs, no sales taxes (cheaper hardware), and the continuing fall in monitor prices; such a service is unlikely to be economically viable in Hong Kong.